# Can't map capslock key using AutoKey

Tags: autokey

My goal is to map <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

When I get to this point, pressing the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key doesn't do anything and will actually crash AutoKey.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. First map your <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key to a <kbd>Hyper</kbd> key adding the below in to a new file in the home directory with the name `.Xmodmap`.

   ```
   clear Lock
   remove mod4 = Hyper_L
   keycode 66 = Hyper_L
   add Lock = Hyper_L
   ```
2. Then autostart this by adding below to one of the startup file, depending on your requirement. (ie. `.xinitrc`, `.bashProfile`, `.Profile` or, if you're using a window manager, adding to the window manager config)
   `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`.
3. Then Autokey will start recognizing your <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key as a <kbd>Hyper</kbd> key